# React-Spring: Invalid Hooks Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-spring

I am trying to learn React-Spring. One of the codes provided in its documentation throws an error when I run it. Any idea what possibly is wrong? How to solve it?

[image]

The code I'm trying to run is-

```
const TextContent = (props) => {

    const [items] = useState([
        { id: '0', title: 'Text1' },
        { id: '1', title: 'Text2' },
        { id: '2', title: 'Text1' }
    ])

    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

    const transitions = useTransition(items[index], index => index.id,
        {
            from: { opacity: 0 },
            enter: { opacity: 1 },
            leave: { opacity: 0 },
            config: { tension: 220, friction: 120 }
        }
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setIndex((state) => (state + 1) % items.length);
        }, 4000)
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    {
        transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
            <animated.div
                key={key}
                style={{ ...props, position: 'absolute' }}
            >
                <p>
                    {item.title}
                </p>
            </animated.div>
        ))
    }
}

export default TextContent;
```

Comment: that's  the entire code for that file?

Comment: @azium I've updated the code.

Comment: do your versions of `react` and `react-dom` match?

Comment: Also, can you include a screenshot of the error?

Comment: @AlDuncanson yes both of them are 16.13.1. I've added the screenshot as well

Comment: @Pratyush please share sandbox link your code is insufficient to draw conclusion

Comment: @Pratyush I tried your code https://codesandbox.io/s/red-leaf-d79hj it working , only change i did was you haven't return from render function ,using all latest react and react-spring

Comment: @rupesh_padhye still not running on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return` statement to your functional component

```js
const TextContent = (props) => {

    const [items] = useState([
        { id: '0', title: 'Text1' },
        { id: '1', title: 'Text2' },
        { id: '2', title: 'Text1' }
    ])

    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

    const transitions = useTransition(items[index], index => index.id,
        {
            from: { opacity: 0 },
            enter: { opacity: 1 },
            leave: { opacity: 0 },
            config: { tension: 220, friction: 120 }
        }
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setIndex((state) => (state + 1) % items.length);
        }, 4000)
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {
              transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
                <animated.div
                    key={key}
                    style={{ ...props, position: 'absolute' }}
                >
                    <p>{item.title}</p>
                </animated.div>
              ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default TextContent;
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-thunder-tnz35?file=/src/App.js) where I got it working

Comment: Doesn't run. I'm starting to believe the problem is with the configuration or something. I tried npm ls to display if I have multiple react-dom or react files. Turns out no.

Comment: Where are you importing `useTransition` from

Comment: I updated my answer with a codesandbox where I got it working by adding a return statement

Comment: I'm importing useTransition from 'react-spring'.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Al Duncanson [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323465/13689893): My problem was in exporting React Fragment instead of actual tag:

```
return (
  <>
    { /* springs.map() */ }
  </>
)
```

Hook started working after I changed it to

```
return (
  <div>
    { /* springs.map() */ }
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In my NextJs app, I got the same issue. In my case, I think it was a cache-related issue. Run the project after removing the ".next" folder fixed the issue. I hope removing the build folder in React will do the same.

And there are two similar functions ("useSpring" and "useSprings"). Make sure to pick the right one for your use case.